# lstlisting directly after section start removes margin before next section

Tags: sectioning, listings

If I place an lstlisting directly after the start of a (sub)section, the margin before the following (sub)section (title) disappears.

Here is a an example document showing the issue:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem
\end{lstlisting}

Sed quis ante nec mi volutpat congue eu id leo.

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Suspendisse at lorem mattis, semper massa id, euismod risus.

\newpage

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem
\end{lstlisting}

Sed quis ante nec mi volutpat congue eu id leo.

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Suspendisse at lorem mattis, semper massa id, euismod risus.

\end{document}
```

And you can see the (annotated) result here:

[image: Annotated screenshot of the PDF created using the example document]

Why is there no margin before the fourth section (title)? Is this a bug in my LaTeX environment (MacTeX-2013), or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say is to be expected since `lstlisting` will be found still in vertical mode and the environment doesn't take any precautions here. You can prevent the undesired result using `\leavevmode` before the offending listing:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\section{Lorem ipsum}
Consectetur adipiscing elit.

\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem
\end{lstlisting}

Sed quis ante nec mi volutpat congue eu id leo.

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Suspendisse at lorem mattis, semper massa id, euismod risus.

\newpage

\section{Lorem ipsum}
\leavevmode\begin{lstlisting}
Lorem
\end{lstlisting}

Sed quis ante nec mi volutpat congue eu id leo.

\section{Dolor sit amet}
Suspendisse at lorem mattis, semper massa id, euismod risus.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works fine! I'll have to read more about this (vertical) mode in LaTeX. Maybe the behavior will make sense then.